# Crear carrito de compras con Session Laravel

Tags: laravel-7

Estoy creando un carro de compras, para cuando un usuario registrado (o no), visite cualquier pagina.
A través de un ShoppingCartProvider, obtengo la session y el id para el carrito.
la envío al modelo, para validar si no existe, que la cree en bd. Pero me está dando este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo del ShoppingCartProvider

```
 public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer("*", function ($view) {
           $session_name = 'shopping_cart_id';
           $shopping_cart_id = Session::get($session_name);
           $shopping_cart = ShoppingCart::findOrCreateBySessionId($shopping_cart_id);// línea 35, sonde marca el error         
           Session::put($session_name, $shopping_cart->id);             
           $view->with('shopping_cart', $shopping_cart);
        });
    }
```

Este es el metodo findOrCreateBySessionId

```
public static function findOrCreateBySessionId($shopping_cart_id){
        if ($shopping_cart_id) {
            return ShoppingCart::find($shopping_cart_id);
        } else {
            return ShoppingCart::create();
        }
    }
```

Al hacer varDump de dd($session_name, $shopping_cart_id); del Session,
me muestra el shopping_cart_id, pero el problema (a mi entender), es que no entra en el else para crear el cart_id.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla shopping_carts

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Les agradezcon de antemano el apoyo.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo lo que dice el error es que estas intentando acceder a una propiedad id y lo que te retorna es shopping_cart_id revisa la tu tabla y cambia el id por el id del carrito (shopping_cart_id) puedes mostrar una imagen de la tabla del carrito para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Hola @Dennis
Acabo de adjuntar la tabla. En el create,  `return ShoppingCart::create();`  .. he quitado el `$shopping_cart->id` y lo crea en la tabla. Pero cada vez que actualizo la página. se crea una fila nueva.